# Is substituting the same as equating two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Maybe a silly question here, but I want to check my understanding. I am looking into the number of intersections between a line and a curve, and finding said number through the discriminant. The steps I’ve been told are:

1. Equate the two functions
2. Move everything to LHS
3. Find the discriminante for resultant quadratic
4. Depending on number of answers we know the number of intersections.

This all makes sense to me. However, one of the solved examples is:
Find the range of values of q for which the line x + 2y = q meets the curve  x(x + y) + 8 = 0
And the first thing they do is rearrange the linear equation for x and then substitute into the quadratic. Once this is done I understand the rest of the process.

But here’s my question. Is this substitution the same as the concept of equating the functions? I’m guessing it is but I’d like to make sure I’m not just making it suit the problem I’m looking at if the reason why the substitution works is another one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same thing. If $x=q-2y$ and $x(x + y) + 8 = 0$ then you could either (a) rearrange the second equation to be $x=$ something and then equate the two values of $x$. Or you could (b) avoid that work and simply substitute $x$ from the first equation into the second.

Comment: Imagine you have two functions, $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$. Since $f(x) = y$, you can substitute $f(x)$ into $y = g(x)$ in place of $y$, which is how you get to $f(x) = g(x)$. So, equating two functions is the same as substitution.

Comment: Great! Thank you both so much for your answers they both helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting @Amaan M: Imagine you have two functions, y=f(x) and y=g(x). Since f(x)=y, you can substitute f(x) into y=g(x) in place of y, which is how you get to f(x)=g(x). So, equating two functions is the same as substitution.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

1. Further to your self-Answer, do be aware that there may be no
   quadratic discriminant to apply your suggested procedure to, since
   *you will not necessarily obtain a quadratic in Step 1.*
2. And even if you do obtain a *quadratic form*, its number of
   solutions isn't necessarily the number of intersections of the two
   given graphs. For example, consider the pair
   $$y=-e^{3-2x},\\y=2e^{3-x}+e^3.$$ Applying your procedure, we
   eventually obtain $$(e^{-x})^2+2(e^{-x})+1=0.$$ So far, so good.
   However, it would be invalid to conclude that because this resultant
   quadratic form has discriminant $0,$ the graphs have exactly $1$
   intersection point; in fact, [they have
   none](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efu7koa7rt).

   [image]

   The reason, of course, is that $e^{-x}={-}1\implies x\notin\mathbb R.$